# Reading bumper state from PR2

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, gazebo-plugins, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System: Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.35-27, 64 bit.
ROS: Latest diamondback from the repositories.

I'm following the PR2 tutorial here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls

Everything works fine, I'm mostly interested in the gripper and I can open and close it using `rostopic`.

What I can't do is read the state of the bumper:
when I execute `rostopic echo l_gripper_l_finger_bumper/state`
I get the following error message:

```
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
```

Executing `rostopic echo /clock` indicates that the clock is indeed being published.

Has anyone else gotten the bumper plugin to work? Any hints/tips?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9368/reading-bumper-state-from-pr2/) by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on 2011-03-14**:
I thought that since it is defined in the relevant .urdf.xarco and since the topic appears, it would be. But I see that I'm wrong. How can I enable the topic?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-10**:
I can't find any reference to "bumper" on that page what makes you think that topic is being publshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, The plugin was not publishing if no contacts exists for the referenced body.  I patched the plugin so bumper publishes regardless it is in contact or not, please see [ticket #4872](http://https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4872) and [patch](http://https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/changeset/36417).

sorry for the confusion.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1